# How to get an array of some parts of a text

Tags: javascript, xregexp

I have some text, including numbers of articles; I need to get an array of these numbers (including the article), after which there are "marker words". f.e. in text:

> "123456/9902/001 one two three hand 123456/9902/002 fat got lot 123456/9902/003 five six 123456/9902/004 seven ten butter"

My resulting array for "marker words"= [hand,ten] will be:

> ["123456/9902/001 one two three hand","123456/9902/004 seven ten butter"]

My code finds something but it works wrong, what would the right regular expression be?

```js
let markers = ["hand", "ten"],
  fin = [];
let num = "(\\d{6}\/\\d{4}\/\\d{3}).*?";
markers.forEach(item => {
  let reg = new RegExp(num + item, 'gmi');
  found = text.match(reg);
  found.forEach(item => fin.push(item));
  if (result) {
    console.log(`for ${item} : ${found.length}`);
    console.log(found);
  } else {
    (console.log('Nothing'))
  }
})
console.log(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first analyze the text using the following code:

```
function findArticles(text) {
  return text.match(/(?:\d{6}\/\d{4}\/\d{3})(?: [a-zA-Z]+)+/g).map(item => item[0])
}
```

Then get article by marker:

```
function getArticleByMarker(articles, marker) {
    let result = null
    articles.forEach(article => article.indexOf(marker) > 0 ? result = article : undefined)
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex to extract the required articles you can use it to split the string into different article names and then filter out those that don't contain the *marker words*. Here is an example:

```js
const markers = ['hand', 'ten']
const str = `123456/9902/001 one two three hand 123456/9902/002 fat got lot 123456/9902/003 five six 123456/9902/004 seven ten butter`;

const articleNames = str.split(/(?=\d{6}\/\d{4}\/\d{3})/);

const articleNamesWithMarkers = articleNames.filter(articleName => markers.some(marker => articleName.includes(marker)));

console.log(articleNamesWithMarkers);
```

Comment: Thank you Titus- have helped me, thank you Cider, that is good too!.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the articles into an array using a look-ahead regex, and then filter that array by a marker-based regular expression:

```js
let text = "123456/9902/001 one two three hand 123456/9902/002 fat got lot 123456/9902/003 five six 123456/9902/004 seven ten butter";

let markers = ["hand","ten"];
let regex = new RegExp("\\b("+markers.join("|")+")\\b", "");
let result = text.split(/(?=\s*\d{6}\/\d{4}\/\d{3})/).filter(art => regex.test(art));

console.log(result);
```

If your markers would contain characters that have a special meaning in regex, you would need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) them.

Comment: like it! thank you, certainly this is what i have been asking